# Json exception causing android device to crash

Tags: android, json

I have a jsonarray that is checked for a value worksheetID which is then stored and used in a variable later on. The problem is that when this value doesn't exist the android device crashes and even though I run it through a try catch block it won't stop it from crashing.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    try
    {
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("WorksheetID");
        Log.v("Worked", "WorksheetID is in ");

    } catch (JSONException e)
    {

       Log.v("failed", "No WorksheetID");
        Log.v("failed", WorksheetID[0]+"");
        e.printStackTrace();


    }

    if(WorksheetID[0] != 0)
    {
        WorksheetID = new int[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            try {
                WorksheetID[i] = jsonArray.getInt(i);
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("failed", "cant do loop 2");
                WorksheetID[0] = 0;

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}catch (Exception e)
{
    WorksheetID[0] = 0;

}
```

Here is the logcat error that I'm getting. for some reason the machine seems to shut down after the first catch without even performing all the lines in the catch itself!

```
    03-21 08:55:42.494  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for WorksheetID
03-21 08:55:42.494  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
03-21 08:55:42.494  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at net.azurewebsites.cosy.Classroom.onCreate(Classroom.java:127)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 08:55:42.498  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy V/failed﹕ No WorksheetID
03-21 08:55:42.506  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-21 08:55:42.506  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d59b20)
03-21 08:55:42.510  21224-21224/net.azurewebsites.cosy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.azurewebsites.cosy, PID: 21224
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.azurewebsites.cosy/net.azurewebsites.cosy.Classroom}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
            at net.azurewebsites.cosy.Classroom.onCreate(Classroom.java:163)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: You're catching a JSONException, but you're getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Maybe you should look for a different cause

Comment: Can post some more code so that we can understand how you declared the array and size of it?

Comment: WorksheetID key parameter not your jsonArray. check your response json format.

Comment: Your are not initializing the WorksheetID array and not putting any data to this array and try to get data from it by WorksheetID[0] != 0

Comment: Can I update your response json format

Comment: Hi @ecribs from your web side you are not sending any data to the jsonArray key i.e  jsonObject.getJSONArray("WorksheetID"); this key don't have any data instead of sending null check null condition and put empty jsonArray if it is null

Comment: if(WorksheetID[0] != 0) you are not intiating your array. try to initiate it before this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

> ```
> if(WorksheetID[0] != 0)
> ```

with

> ```
> if(WorksheetID.length > 0 && WorksheetID[0] != 0)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As you're getting an ArrayIndexOut ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException whenever WorksheetID is null, you may be doing something wrong with an array in the Catch-block.

A possible culprit is this line:

> Log.v("failed", WorksheetID[0]+"");

It looks that the array is empty or not initialized and you're trying to access the first element (which is empty), hence you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Make sure that WorksheetID is initialized before trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of mistakes in ur code and its not clear what you actually doing.

Try this

```
 try
    {

      if(jsonObject.has("WorksheetID")){

      jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("WorksheetID");


       int[] WorksheetID = new int[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            try {
                WorksheetID[i] = jsonArray.getInt(i);
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("failed", "cant do loop 2");

            }
        }


        }else{
           Log.v("NoWorksheet", "No WorksheetID  available");
        }


    } catch (JSONException e)
    {

       Log.v("failed", "No WorksheetID");
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, not `JSONException` that is why it crashes because it's not able to catch the type of exception. Even if you used another try-catch statement that will catch a general exception error, it won't be able to reach that part since the error occurs on the second try-catch statement. Change your `JSONException` to `Exception` on your second catch statement if you want your app not to crash.